# All ObjectEvents created share similar source information?

Tags: java, events

Any time that I use an ObjectEvent, every statement in it's "performed" method is called. With ActionEvent, if I put separate action commands from different objects, every action command is called for every object. Similarly, using a public library, jnativehook, it utilizes global screen listening for the keyboard/mouse. There are individual constants defined to describe each key from the keyboard pressed, but each "NativeKeyEvent" (the Object event) performs every command despite conditional statements. In Context:

@Override

```
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {
    NativeKeyEvent e = nativeKeyEvent;
    Color col;
    Piece.TetColor t;

    if(e.getKeyCode() == (NativeKeyEvent.VC_SPACE));
    {
        System.out.println("Space Pressed");

    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ESCAPE);
    {
        System.out.println("Escape Pressed");
    }
}
```

This is the action performed of the NativeKeyEvent. No matter what key I press, it will always print out:
`Space Pressed
Escape Pressed`

I had this problem earlier in the year with ActionEvents and their event commands but just wrote separate anonymous classes for every case I wanted to handle. I'm very confused and would appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple typo in your method. There should be no semi-colon (`;`) after your if statement. By putting a semi-colon there, the `println` statement following it is no longer part of the if statement.

Instead use:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_SPACE)
     System.out.println("Space Pressed");
else if(e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ESCAPE)
    System.out.println("Escape Pressed");
```

Or:

```
switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
case NativeKeyEvent.VC_SPACE:
    System.out.println("Space Pressed"); break;
case NativeKeyEvent.VC_ESCAPE:
    System.out.println("Escape Pressed"); break;
}
```